# Using requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter for testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests

I'm trying to test some requests codes by providing a mocked out TestAdapter my session object. Basically, my code looks like this:

```
URL = 'http://blahblahblah'

class TestAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, response):
        self._response = response
        super(TestAdapter, self).__init__()

    def send(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.build_response(request, self._response)

resp = urllib3\
    .HTTPResponse(body=json.dumps({'results': results}), status=200,
                  headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
adapter = TestAdapter(resp)
session = requests.Session()
session.mount(URL, adapter)

response = session.post(URL)
response.json()
```

However, this use raises an error from the depths of URLLib3:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_web_cache_client.py", line 40, in test_valid_reponse
    response.json()
  File "/home/wilner/.virtualenvs/hub/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 778, in json
    if not self.encoding and len(self.content) > 3:
  File "/home/wilner/.virtualenvs/hub/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 724, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "/home/wilner/.virtualenvs/hub/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 653, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/home/wilner/.virtualenvs/hub/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 255, in stream
    while not is_fp_closed(self._fp):
  File "/home/wilner/.virtualenvs/hub/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/response.py", line 22, in is_fp_closed
    raise ValueError("Unable to determine whether fp is closed.")
ValueError: Unable to determine whether fp is closed.
```

I could definitely find another way of testing this stuff, but this seems like it should work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just mock `session.post()`? You want to test the call to that function, not the internals of `requests` here.

Comment: Yes, as I mention in the post, I could find other ways of testing this. I could defend the merits of testing it in this way, but the question is not so much about the proper way of testing as it is about the appropriate way of extending the adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

[Betamax](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/betamax) is a library that does something very similar to what you want. The way I do it in betamax can be found [here](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/betamax/blob/ec077d93cf95b65456819b86174af31d025f0d3c/betamax/cassette/util.py#L118) (and is reproduced below for posterity):

```
def add_urllib3_response(serialized, response):
    if 'base64_string' in serialized['body']:
        body = io.BytesIO(
            base64.b64decode(serialized['body']['base64_string'].encode())
        )
    else:
        body = body_io(**serialized['body'])
    h = HTTPResponse(
        body,
        status=response.status_code,
        headers=response.headers,
        preload_content=False,
        original_response=MockHTTPResponse(response.headers)
    )
    response.raw = h
```

The important thing here is that `body` (the first parameter) to `HTTPResponse` is a `io.BytesIO` object in every case. If you ensure you're using bytes, e.g., `json.dumps({'results': results}).encode('utf-8')` needs to be passed to `io.BytesIO`.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around this by setting `requests.Response._content = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter._body` to avoid the erroneous fp check.  I think this is a bug in the library.